# define tikzpicture size with standalone document class

Tags: tikz-pgf

When drawing with standalone document class, the output image will automatically centered. for example, if I draw a circle with 5cm, then the image output will be 5cm. How can I keep 5cm circle in the center but output image size keep to 10cm?
I know the border=5cm option but I wish to use some command to define the picture dimension then I can always get the exact size, say 10cmx10cm.

Comment: What do you mean by *picture dimension*? Do you want the paper size? You can use `geometry` package to control everything, paper size, margins, and so on.

Comment: I mean use fixed picture size to draw something on it.

Comment: So, you want to draw any picture on a page sized 10x10?

Comment: yes, use specific size then draw on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a bounding box to the `tikzpicture`. Then you can freely arrange objects therein.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
  \filldraw (-5,-5) rectangle ++(1,1);
  \draw(0,0)circle(2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `2.5 cm` border on each side with the standalone option `border=2.5cm`, since `2.5cm+5cm+2.5 cm=10cm`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw(0,0)circle(2.5cm);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,minimum size=20cm]{};
\draw(0,0)circle(5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lucky1928 This comment was for my answer?